# In the integral down below, when are the limits applied once you have done the calculations?

Tags: calculus, integration

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{x} t \sin (t) d t
\end{equation}

From this problem I have recognized that this is integration by parts so from here I computed

\begin{equation}
(t)(-\cos t)-\int-\cos (t) d t
\end{equation}

Then I integrated which comes out to

\begin{equation}
\int-\cos (t) d t \Rightarrow-\sin (t)
\end{equation}

Hence combining this we get

\begin{equation}
-t \cos (t)--\sin (t)
\end{equation}

At this stage is there any simplification I would need to do or is this answer valid and acceptable? Would I just substitute the limits in and compute the final answer?

Comment: $-t\cos(t) + \sin(t) + C$?

Comment: There are limits in the integral I will edit the question for clarity

Comment: Sure.  I just think life will be easier if you convert the subtraction by $-\sin(t)$ into addition by $\sin(t)$.

Comment: Ah yes since two negatives make a positive, thanks for spotting it

Comment: Please don't use displayed math in subject lines.

Comment: The only simplification would be to combine the two minus signs, add a plus $C$, and then yes substitute limits

Comment: @FrankW So the final answer coming out to be sin(x)-xcos(x) when applying the limits?

Comment: @AMN That looks right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem of integration by parts is a result of the fundamental theorem of calculus and the product rule for derivatives. Suppose that you have two differentiable real-valued functions $u,v:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, then setting $f=u\cdot v$ you have that

$$
\int_{a}^bdf=f(b)-f(a)\implies \int_{a}^bd(u\cdot v)=\int_{a}^b (udv+vdu)=u(b)\cdot v(b)-u(a)\cdot v(a)\\
\therefore\quad \int_{a}^b udv=u(b)v(b)-u(a)v(a)-\int_{a}^bvdu
$$

In your case if you choose $u(t)=t$ and $dv=\sin (t)\,d t$ you get

$$
\int_{0}^x t\sin (t)\,d t=-\cos (x)\cdot x+\cos (0)\cdot 0+\int_{0}^x \cos (t)\,d t=-\cos (x)\cdot x+\sin (x)
$$